# Dataset makes frame and axis marks vanish

Tags: graphics

Perhaps `Dataset` isn't ready to handle graphics objects yet, but:

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}]
Dataset@plot
```

[image]

The axis marks have vanished.

Similarly, frame ticks vanish when put inside a `Dataset`:

```
plot = DateListPlot[
  FinancialData["GLD", "Close", {"Jan 1, 2017", "June 1, 2017"}]]
Dataset@plot
```

[image]

The same issue happens for other types of plots (like `ListLinePlot`, `LogPlot`, etc.). Currently using V10.2 on Windows.

Comment: Works fine in v11.1 (although doesn't in 10.4).

Comment: So, what is the question? (Still working fine in 11.3).